# how to solve different emoji on textarea field between windows and mac

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

i have chatbot, in the textarea i can add emoji like this

[image]

i'm using this library called ngx-emoj https://github.com/ahkohd/ngx-emoj but when i open the chatbot in mac here's what it looks like

[image]

it's overlapping, is it because the font for emoji is not the same? both windows and mac, the font family is the same using roboto. Did anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you use the same font i.e., Roboto, It is Apple who decides which font their web-browsers should display. In windows, the Emojis are in Microsoft's Font (if you closely notice, the flat emojis are not in roboto, they are in Microsoft Emoji). In Mac, I think Apple uses Helvetica for Emojis.

This happens because, Operating System Developers, Override your preferences in case of Emojis but do not override for normal text. That is why the text will look same but Emojis wont despite you setting Roboto in both.

I think the library you are using is not optimized for Mac. The better option would be allowing the Operating System's Default Emoji Picker to function. i.e. (Win + Period) in Windows, etc.

It looks like this on linux: (I used the GitHub Project you mentioned)
[image: Look on Linux]

An from your website:
[image]

Comment: ok so its not actually a problem right? but its just because each OS is using different emoji, but do you know to prevent this? i mean, on my windows the letter-spacing using normal and its fine, but in mac i need to set it to 0.5em

Comment: There are some workarounds, but they mostly do not work due to the **retina-display** of Macs. Lot programmers have this problem.

Comment: hmm ok, can u try my chat plugin here and make a screenshot pls?  chat.alfaprav.com how the emoji looks like on your machine

Comment: I've updated the answer with a screenshot, I use elementary OS Odin

Comment: the problem only appear on the mac, i think  it should be fine isn't it?

Comment: It's Fine. Moreover, the problem is with Macs using **retina-display** which I read in a few blogs.